# Share code across TFS folders (like svn:externals)?

Tags: version-control, tfs

I have multiple projects with common in-house JavaScript library dependencies. I want to share these dependencies across multiple projects.

Unfortunately we are using TFS. I'd like something like svn:externals, whereby I can link a particular folder to a different folder elsewhere in the source control tree. So I want to have

```
ProjectA
  app
  js
    lib [should link to SharedProject/lib]

ProjectB
  app
  js
    lib [should link to SharedProject/lib]

SharedProject
  lib
    library1.js
    library2.js
```

I don't want to link across workspaces...I don't want a crazy custom per-developer setup. I just want developers to check out one project, and it knows "Oh, there are shared resources in this other project. I'll get those too." I don't care about it always getting a specific version; I'm just tired of copying files across projects.

Is this remotely possible in TFS? I have Googled and found nothing conclusive.

Comment: So, why are we voting to close this? If you believe this is neither a "real" nor a "constructive" question, please explain your reasoning rather than cowarding.

Comment: Voting to close because its a rant not a question. Chill out and remove the emotion and you might get an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just branch the shared project from its original location to where you want it to be.

When you would switch to next revision on svn:externals, simply merge changes up to that revision to the branched copy.

(frankly I prefer this way even on SVN)

Comment: Does this require a checkout of ProjectA and then an additional checkout of SharedProject into a subdirectory of ProjectA, by each developer?

Comment: Nope, SharedProject will be physically a subfolder of ProjectA and will be checked out just like any other sub-item of ProjectA. The fact it was branched from the original place will allow you to easily merge changes from that original place.

Answer (score 1):

Using external link in source is not a good idea. It creates lot of side effects. You can package and publish your library using NuGet to a private NuGet server and then consume the published packages in all the dependent projects.